# PHPMailer doesnt give error messages or send emails just a white screen

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I am trying to send emails using PHP mailer. Nothing happens all I get is a white screen in the web browser. I have used different examples of code changed ssl to tls port 587 to 465 used require the autoload.php phpmailer.php smtp.php anything I can find to get an indication as to where the problem is. The code is exactly the same as the one on https://subinsb.com/send-mails-via-smtp-server-gmail-outlook-php apart from the email credentials etc. Any ideas you may have or if you see something I don't would be appreciated.

```
<?php
$account = "xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com";
$password = 'xxxxxx';
$from = 'xxxxxxxx@gmail.com';
$from_name = 'Adam Johnson';
$subject = 'Test';
$msg = 'This is a test';
$to = "xxxxxxxxx@hotmail.com";

require ('/PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php');

$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->Username = $account;
$mail->Password = $password;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->From = $from;
$mail->FromName = $from_name;
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body = $msg;
$mail->addAddress($to);

if (!mail->send()){
echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
else {
echo 'Message sent!';
}
?>
```

Comment: Blank screen *(a.k.a. white screen of death*): Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: If you're using latest PHPMailer, loading only the main class instead of the autoloader, and then trying to use SMTP, it will not work. Read the docs, this is right there in the readme example.

Comment: @ Fred I added the code but still give a white screen. @Synchro I tried autoloader as well I tried to ass class.smtp.php too all three together no difference...

Comment: Add `echo 'hello';` at the beginning of your script and gradually move it down until you don't see it. That will tell you where the script is going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this

```
require ('/PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php');

$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;
$mail = new PHPMailer();
```

should look like this;

```
require ('/PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php');

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;
```

You've not initialed the `$mail` variable yet in your code, yet you're trying to set `$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;` on an non existent object.

**EDIT**

One more typo in the code. The line `if (!mail->send()){` is missing the `$` variable declaration. Make sure it reads `if (!$mail->send()){`

Comment: Yes you are right. I changed that as well and still nothing. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: see my edit. You're also missing the `$` from `$mail->send()`. That *should* fix your WSOD. If there are more errors however, then turning on error reporting as suggested in other comments should help.